# Determine CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture for an arbitrary HttpContext

Tags: .net, asp.net, localization, httpcontext

Given an instance of an `HttpContext` object, is there a way to determine the `CurrentCulture` and/or `CurrentUICulture` for the thread it is executing on? Or more generally, is there a way to gain access to the current thread under which it is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext` has an internal property called `DynamicCulture` which you can read with reflection but it could change in the future.  If this property is not populated, then the culture can be defined by the relevant Web.config or the Page.

If you're caching `HttpContext` objects and passing them between threads (probably a very bad idea anyways), then the most reliable way to also access the relevant culture is to wrap both the `HttpContext` and `CurrentCulture` into a custom class and pass that.

Comment: Thanks for the info; for a little background, I'm using an arbitrary 3rd party component that takes an HttpContext as an argument in one of its functions; I need to perform a localization operation based on this. My other option is simply to stow these values in the Context.Items collection, which is the route I will take if there isn't a more direct way to get these values.

Comment: @DanP, using the `Context.Items` collections sounds like a great place to store the culture.

Comment: a shame that there isn't a more direct way, but this will work for my purposes; thanks!